When a hostage is in the balance, how much is one expected to comply before they face legal trouble?
Terry the Terrorist has Holly as a Hostage at gunpoint. Bob the random Bystander happens to be there, and Terry starts making demands of him (else Terry will kill the hostage). Let's also say that William the Witness is there to tell the police/jury about everything afterwards.
Is Bob at all responsible for following (or not following) the demands of Terry? As a few examples:

Terry asks Bob to chop off Holly the hostage's left arm, or else he'll kill her. If Bob complies, did he do anything wrong? If Bob doesn't comply and Holly gets killed, did Bob do anything wrong?
Terry asks Bob to chop off his own left arm, or else he'll kill Holly. If Bob doesn't comply (and this gets Holly killed), is Bob at all liable?
Terry asks Bob to jump twice, or else he'll kill Holly. Bob refuses (even though it wouldn't cost him or anyone anything). Terry then kills Holly because of Bob's refusal. Is Bob responsible for not complying with something so simple and getting Holly killed?
Terry tells Bob that he'll let him live if he kills Holly right there. If Bob kills Holly, is he off the hook legally?

To summarize the crux of the examples: 1: Bob must hurt the hostage for their sake, 2: But must hurt himself for the hostage, 3: Bob is under no duress, and can basically decide whether the hostage dies through inaction, 4: Bob has to choose between himself and the hostage.
Obviously, Terry is responsible and isn't going to have a good time in court. My question is about what is expected of Bob so that he doesn't face legal repercussion.
P.S.: A stealth interpretation for this question is abortion: if Bob is the "mother" and Holly is the baby, and Terry (nature/government) says "go through intense pain or else kill Holly", is Bob obliged to go through with it? This is most similar to the second example I stated, I think.

#4 seems like self-defense, Bob is allowed to do what's necessary to defend himself. In all the other cases, Terry committed premeditated murder; the fact that Bob could have prevented it is irrelevant.

@Jen I'd say the overlap between the subquestions renders this suitable to be presented as a single question.

But I'd agree the "stealth interpretation" is unhelpful, especially given the obvious differences between threatening to kill a hostage and regulating abortions.

Afaik law says that there is an obligation to help only in things what you expected to do :-) For example, a swimming master can be expected to save someone drowning in water, but a bystander not. And most people are psychologically incapable to chop off the arms of others. Thus, the hostage will die, the bystander will be innocent and the whole criminal responsibility will be on the terrorist.

Example #1

Is Bob at all responsible for following (or not following) the demands
of Terry? As a few examples:
Terry asks Bob to chop off Holly the hostage's left arm, or else he'll
kill her. If Bob complies, did he do anything wrong? If Bob doesn't
comply and Holly gets killed, did Bob do anything wrong?

Bob committed the crime of aggravated assault but probably prevails on the affirmative defense of duress if the threat was credible. See California Penal Code § 26. The pertinent part of that statute states that:

All persons are capable of committing crimes except . . . . Persons
(unless the crime be punishable with death) who committed the act or
made the omission charged under threats or menaces sufficient to show
that they had reasonable cause to and did believe their lives would be
endangered if they refused.

Aggravated assault is not punishable by death.
Example #2

Terry asks Bob to chop off his own left arm, or else he'll kill Holly.
If Bob doesn't comply (and this gets Holly killed), is Bob at all
liable?

No. Bob doesn't have any affirmative legal duty to help Holly in the face of certain serious injury to himself, and cutting off his own arm is serious enough that it would endanger his life.
Example #3

Terry asks Bob to jump twice, or else he'll kill Holly. Bob refuses
(even though it wouldn't cost him or anyone anything). Terry then
kills Holly because of Bob's refusal. Is Bob responsible for not
complying with something so simple and getting Holly killed?

No. In California, Bob has no legal duty, even if he can rescue at no material harm or risk to himself. A legal omission that gives rise to criminal liability requires some legal duty to take the omitted act. Bob will feel horribly about himself in this case, but he isn't legally responsible for Holly's death.
Example #4

Terry tells Bob that he'll let him live if he kills Holly right there.
If Bob kills Holly, is he off the hook legally?

If killing Holly is an offense punishable by death in California, then the duress defense of California Penal Code § 26 does not relieve Bob of criminal culpability. If it is not punishable by death, then it does relieve Bob of criminal culpability.
When Bob intentionally kills Holly, he has clearly committed murder. The question is whether Bob has committed first degree murder under California law under circumstances that make him eligible for the death penalty.
California's first degree murder statutes are found at California Penal Code Sections 187-199. Section 187 states in the pertinent part that:

Murder is the unlawful killing of a human being . . . with malice
aforethought.

Section 188 states:

(a) For purposes of Section 187, malice may be express or implied.
(1) Malice is express when there is manifested a deliberate intention
to unlawfully take away the life of a fellow creature.
(2) Malice is implied when no considerable provocation appears, or
when the circumstances attending the killing show an abandoned and
malignant heart.
(3) Except as stated in subdivision (e) of Section 189, in order to be
convicted of murder, a principal in a crime shall act with malice
aforethought. Malice shall not be imputed to a person based solely on
his or her participation in a crime.
(b) If it is shown that the killing resulted from an intentional act
with express or implied malice, as defined in subdivision (a), no
other mental state need be shown to establish the mental state of
malice aforethought. Neither an awareness of the obligation to act
within the general body of laws regulating society nor acting despite
that awareness is included within the definition of malice.

Section 189 states in the pertinent parts:

(a) All murder that is perpetrated . .  by any other kind of willful,
deliberate, and premeditated killing . . . .  is murder of the first
degree.
(b) All other kinds of murders are of the second degree. . . .
(d) To prove the killing was “deliberate and premeditated,” it is not
necessary to prove the defendant maturely and meaningfully reflected
upon the gravity of the defendant's act[.]

The hard question would be whether the duress was a provocation that caused Bob's act to not constitute malice, and whether Bob's killing of Holly was "willful, deliberate and premeditated" under these circumstances.
Penal Code § 26 seems to disfavor a conclusion that the duress can constitute provocation, because otherwise duress would always rule out first degree murder under Penal Code § 187. But it could be that there are other first degree murder offenses where provocation is not an issue (e.g. if you were already involved in a felony, a part of Section § 189 that was omitted). And, the rule of leniency applies to interpreting criminal codes, so if there is an interpretation of an ambiguity favorable to Bob and it doesn't render Section 26 meaningless or absurd, he should benefit from the favorable reading.
If the duress does constitute provocation, then the the issue is whether Bob's killing of Holly was willful, deliberate, and premeditated. Given that he was asked to do it and intentionally killed Holly, Bob's murder of Holly was probably willful and deliberate. So, the availability of the duress defense to Bob hinges on whether or not his murder of Holly was premeditated.
The statute tells us that premeditated does not mean that Bob "maturely and meaningfully reflected upon the gravity of" his act. But we'd need California case law to figure out what premeditated does mean.
On one hand, until Bob walked into this situation he'd never met Holly, didn't intend to kill her, and even once he was sucked into it, never even considered killing Holly until he was suddenly threatened with his own death if he didn't kill her right then. This is not the kind of advanced planning we associate with premeditation, and we can imagine someone doing careful advance planning but thinking of it as a game rather than something real and not contemplating that this was all very seriously bad, so it doesn't necessarily render the statute absurd if read in that way.
On the other hand, when Bob killed Holly he wasn't acting impulsively either. He was given a choice by Terry, weighed it, and decided to value his own life more than Holly, who was an innocent victim herself. But the fact that Bob was told by Terry that Bob had to do it  "right there" helps support the argument that when Bob kills Holly that it isn't premeditated murder.
On balance, Bob is probably going to be allowed to invoke the duress defense in this situation and the prosecutors are probably going to cut him some slack and not even try to charge him if he cooperates as a witness in the case. He is clearly much less culpable than Terry in this case. But, Bob's criminal liability in this case is a much closer call than in the other three examples where Bob's lack of criminal liability is clear.
Stealth Question

A stealth interpretation for this question is abortion: if Bob is the
"mother" and Holly is the baby, and Terry (nature/government) says "go
through intense pain or else kill Holly", is Bob obliged to go through
with it?

Abortion is legal in California so this stealth interpretation does not apply in California law. There can be murder charges for causing the termination of fetus in California, but only if it is done without the consent of the mother in a some sort of criminal assault on the mother.

In the case of abortion, there's also the question of whether a fetus is legally a "person". Under Roe, I think the general rule was that it's not a person prior to viability, which is why abortion wasn't murder. Since Dobbs, each state sets its own definition.

@Barmar California Penal Code § 187 expressly includes fetuses in its definitions of murder in a portion that I omitted because it wasn't relevant to examples #1-#4, but this has to be read together with California abortion laws to glean that in the context of first degree murder it is not referring to medical abortions with the consent of the mother.

Of course, one of the reasons why abortion is such a controversial issue is that it's like the "trolley problem" -- either way you go, someone is being harmed. The analogies that the OP is trying to make don't really help, because there's not really anyone analogous to Terry.

That seems a bit incongruous...
